# Why is this implementation of Quick Sort slower than qsort?

Tags: c, performance, sorting, quicksort

Doing some refreshing on algorithms. I wrote this Quick sort implementation:

```
#define SWAP(X, Y, Type) { Type Temp = (X); (X) = (Y); (Y) = Temp; }

int QSPartition(int* Array, int StartIndex, int EndIndex)
{
    int PivotDestinationIndex = StartIndex;
    int Pivot = Array[EndIndex];
    for(int i = StartIndex; i <= EndIndex; i++)
    {
        if (Array[i] < Pivot)
        {
            SWAP(Array[i], Array[PivotDestinationIndex], int);
            PivotDestinationIndex++;
        }
    }
    SWAP(Array[PivotDestinationIndex], Array[EndIndex], int);
    return PivotDestinationIndex;
}

void QuickSort(int* Array, int StartIndex, int EndIndex)
{
    if (StartIndex >= EndIndex)
        return;

    int PivotIndex = QSPartition(Array, StartIndex, EndIndex);
    QuickSort(Array, PivotIndex + 1, EndIndex);
    QuickSort(Array, StartIndex, PivotIndex - 1);
}
```

In my main program:

```
#define Measure(Iterations, What, Code)\
{\
    clock_t Begin = clock();\
    for(int _im_ = 0; _im_ < Iterations; _im_++)\
    {\
        Code;\
    }\
    clock_t End = clock();\
    printf("Time took to " What ": %.1f ms\n", (double)(End - Begin));\
}

int CompareInt(const void* x, const void* y) { return *(int*)x - *(int*)y; }

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    int Count = 100000;
    int* Array0 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * Count);
    int* Array1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        int RandomValue = rand() % 100;
        Array0[i] = RandomValue;
        Array1[i] = RandomValue;
    }

    Measure(1, "My Quick", QuickSort(Array0, 0, Count - 1));
    Measure(1, "C  Quick", qsort(Array1, Count, sizeof(int), CompareInt));

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is that "My Quick" is always around `125 ms` while "C Quick" is always around `25 ms`. (32-bit DEBUG build - On RELEASE still the same 5 times slower)

What is going on? Why is my implementation slower? (I tried inlining the functions but it didn't do much) Is there something else wrong? (the way I'm timing this, or the way I'm populating the arrays with random values, or...?)

Comment: qsort is a quick sort. it is not necessarily an implementation of quicksort.

Comment: @Downvoter, care to elaborate?

Comment: @DanielA.White tried it, didn't help much

Comment: I don't get the negative votes...

Comment: there could be some optimizations to use some cpu instructions that manually written code isn't taking advantage of

Comment: Many qsorts switch over to a non-quicksort algorithm in situations where quicksort is less than ideal.  If memory serves, MSVC's will switch to a heapsort when you get under 16 elements.

Comment: I haven't run any tests, but one big difference is the fact that `qsort` is usually optimised by dropping down to another sort when the size is small. You can see it in the [glibc `qsort` source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/qsort.c): insertion sort when there's 4 elements or less. It is also iterative, not recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these, you'll need to change the std::swap to swap for C.

QuickSort using middle value for pivot:

```
void QuickSort(uint32_t a[], int lo, int hi) {
    int i = lo, j = hi;
    uint32_t pivot = a[(lo + hi) / 2];
    while (i <= j) {            // partition
        while (a[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (a[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            std::swap(a[i], a[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (lo < j)                 // recurse
        QuickSort(a, lo, j);
    if (i < hi)
        QuickSort(a, i, hi);
}
```

QuickSort using median of low, middle, high, values as pivot

```
void QuickSort(uint32_t a[], int lo, int hi) {
    int i = lo, j = (lo + hi)/2, k = hi;
    uint32_t pivot;
    if (a[k] < a[i])            // median of 3
        std::swap(a[k], a[i]);
    if (a[j] < a[i])
        std::swap(a[j], a[i]);
    if (a[k] < a[j])
        std::swap(a[k], a[j]);
    pivot = a[j];
    while (i <= k) {            // partition
        while (a[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (a[k] > pivot)
            k--;
        if (i <= k) {
            std::swap(a[i], a[k]);
            i++;
            k--;
        }
    }
    if (lo < k)                 // recurse
        QuickSort(a, lo, k);
    if (i < hi)
        QuickSort(a, i, hi);
}
```

Comment: Well both of these are faster than my implementation and qsort... But why? does the choice of the pivot really matter that much? I guess also less function calls for partitioning

Comment: @vexe - for pseudo random data, the choice of pivot should not matter. I made a modified version of your code with the partition logic inline instead of a separate function. It's still slower, most likely due to my examples including a check for values > pivot (Hoare partition scheme). Look at the wiki article on [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) for more on this.

Comment: I was actually just looking at @vexe's partitioning algorithm since I was thinking it was doing redundant compares.  I think it's not actually redundant compares that's the problem, it's that it doesn't care where it swaps *to*.  The upward/downward indices ensure that both halves of the swap are useful, rather than **swapping an element with itself** while incrementing `pivotdest`.  It could also stop one element sooner, because comparing pivot against itself is useless.  In the already-sorted case, vexe's partitioning swaps *every* element with itself, because `PD == i` every iteration.

Comment: The wiki article goes on to mention that using [median of medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) with n/5 factor for quicksort pivot reduces the worst case to O(n log(n)), but the overhead for this makes it slower in the average case. Mergesort is probably faster than quicksort using median of medians (n/5). If 16 registers are available, such as X86 in 64 bit mode, then a 4 way merge sort using most of the registers as pointers is about as fast as quicksort best case, and much faster worst case.

Comment: @PeterCordes not sure how it's swapping an element with itself, could you give an example with numbers please?

Comment: @vexe: sure, start with `1 5 7 6 1 4  pivot=4  pd=0.  before loop`.  On the `i=0`, iteration, i=0 and pd=0, so it swaps `a[0]` with `a[0]`, then increments `pd`.  Just open up a text editor and trace it for yourself.  Make a line for each iteration, like **3**: `1 5 7 6 1 4  pivot=4  i=3  pd=1`,  **4**:  `1 1 7 6 5 4  pivot=4  i=4  pd=2`, **5**: `1 1 7 6 5 4  pivot=4  i=5  pd=2  useless compare of pivot against itself`.  Also check out the case where `pivot` is the largest element.  Your code can't increment PivotDestinationIndex without doing a swap.

Comment: I see. I tried having `i` start from `StartIndex + 1` but it made little to no difference in the benchmark time. EDIT scratch that, that's actually causing incorrect sorting. Instead I modified the if statement condition `if (Array[i] < Pivot && i != PivotDestinationIndex)` but still similar performance